# Multiple Different Files upload Using Multer + Node JS - Postman

Tags: node.js, postman, multer

Is it possible to upload two different files(different extensions) into different folders using multer + node JS. multer(1.3.0).

I am getting an Error: "Unexpected field"

```
//uploading content code here

   router.post('/v1/uploads', function(req, res){

  //uploading the cover
  //set storage engine for COVER
  var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination : './uploads/covers/',
    filename: function(req, file, callback){
      callback(null, randomString.generate(10) + "_"+ Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
  });

  //init upload for cover
  var upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits:{fileSize: 50 * 1024 * 1024},
    fileFilter: function(req, file, callback) {
      checkFileTypeCover(file,callback)
    }
  }).single('artwork');

  upload(req,res, (err) => {
    if(err){
      res.json({
        success: false,
        message: 'upload failed cover with an error : '+err
      });
    }else{
      if(req.file == 'undefined'){
        res.json({
          success: false,
          message: 'failed to upload the file on the server for cover'
        });
      }else{

        console.log('we have uploaded an image');

        multer = '';

        var storage2 = multer2.diskStorage({
          destination : './uploads/content/',
          filename: function(req, file, callback){
            callback(null, randomString.generate(10) + "_"+ Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
          }
        });


        //init upload for cover
        var upload2 = multer2({
          storage: storage2,
          limits:{fileSize: 50 * 1024 * 1024},
          fileFilter: function(req, file, callback) {
            checkfile(file,callback)
          }
        }).single('pdf');

        //upload image successfully, then upload pdf with new cover name
        //uploading the pdf

        upload2(req, res, (err) => {
          if(err){
            res.json({
              success: false,
              message: 'upload failed pdf with an error : '+err
            });
          }else{

            if(req.file == 'undefined'){
              res.json({
                success: false,
                message: 'failed to upload the file on the server'
              });
            }else{

              console.log('we have uploaded a pdf');

                /*

                //pdf file url for the content
                var pdf_url = req.file.filename;
                var title = req.body.title;
                var description = req.body.description;
                var free = req.body.free;
                var content_type = req.body.content_type;
                var category = req.body.category;
                var publisher = req.body.publisher;

                var newzine = new Newzine();
                newzine.title = title;
                newzine.description = description;

                if(free != null){
                  newzine.free = free;
                }
                if(content_type !=null){
                  newzine.content_type = content_type;
                }
                newzine.category = category;
                newzine.publisher = publisher;
                newzine.cover_url = 'no_image.png';
                newzine.pdf_url = pdf_url;

                //save the newzine on the mongo db database
                newzine.save(function(err){
                  if(err){
                    res.json({
                      success: false,
                      message: 'uploaded failed',
                      error: err
                    });
                  }else{
                    res.json({
                      success: true,
                      message: 'file uploaded successful'
                    });
                  }
                });
              }
          }  
        }); 
      }
    }
  });
```

});

And the following i check for image and cover

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
 destination : './uploads/content/',
 filename: function(req, file, callback){
 callback(null, randomString.generate(10) + "-"+  Date.now()+path.extname(file.originalname));
 }
});

var upload = multer({
 storage: storage,
 limits:{fileSize: 50 * 1024 * 1024},
 fileFilter: function(req, file, callback) {
 checkFileTypePDF(file,callback)
 }
}).single('pdf');

 //check file type here for pdf
  function checkFileTypePDF(file, callback){
  // Allow only PDF extensions
   const fileTypes = /pdf|PDF/;
  //check extension
  const extname = fileTypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());
  //check mime type
  const mimetype = fileTypes.test(file.mimeType);

 if(extname){
   return callback(null,true);
 }else{
  callback('only pdf is allowed');
 }
}

//check file type here for cover
 function checkFileTypeCover(file, callback){
 // Allow only Image extensions
 const fileTypes = /jpg/;
 //check extension
 const extname =  fileTypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());
 console.log('the ext name is '+extname);
 //check mime type
 const mimetype = fileTypes.test(file.mimeType);
 console.log('the mimetype is '+mimetype);

 if(extname){
   return callback(null,true);
 }else{
  callback('only images are allowed');
  }
}
```

I'm uploading image and pdf using postman, but it is failing on postman, as it does not allow two files to be uploaded at the sametime. Only one file can be uploaded at a time.

Comment: You should always add your own code for clarity of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I would like if you could upload your code. 
I,ll post a very general method here for your reference.In any case, multer doesn't mind multiple uploads or extensions at least according to its default settings.
A sample front end code :

```
<form action="PathOfYourChoice" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Select image to upload:
<input type="file" name="ANY_NAME_YOU_WANT" id="fileToUpload" multiple="">
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

Use this form for multiple uploads of any file extensions. note that you only need to have multiple attribute(no value necessary) in the html tag.

At the backend, give your storage config e.g

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({//further options to be specified after 
discussion
destination: function(req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, destination_fileupload(a variable,you should set the 
path))
},
filename: function(req, file, callback) {
    //filename schema has to be changed.Further decision pending on naming 
scheme
    callback(null, Date.now()+"-"+file.originalname)
}
});
```

At your route at the backend ,e.g

```
router.post("/PathOfYourChoice",function(req,res){
var upload = multer({
    storage: storage
    }).array('ANY_NAME_YOU_WANT'); //use .singleif you want only single file 
upload . Al
upload(req,res,function(err){
if(err)
    throw err;
res.send("files uploaded")
})
```

One thing to notice is that the string inside the .array method MUST be the same as the name you give to the input element inside your form html. The same is the case with your path you specified in the form action attribute and your route path.

Comment: There are two input files, i will post the code shortly. Your method upload array of the object of the same type. e.g images @Omer

Comment: Well you can upload any file using the same code.An image can have different extensions like jpeg and PNG so i thought may be this was what you would want. In any case, I have now tested with a PNG(image) file and psd(photoshop) file and there wasn't any error as such. Both files uploaded fine

Comment: I have udated my qn @NileshSingh

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this approach:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        let filextPos = file
                .originalname
                .lastIndexOf('.'),
            filext = file
                .originalname
                .substring(filextPos)

        if (filext === 'jpg') {
           cb(null, './public/images/jpgs/')
        } else {
           cb(null, './public/images/pngs/')
        }
    }
});

const uploader = multer({storage: storage}).single('img');
```

What we are doing here is change the default upload path depending on the file (image) extension.

Further, we use the uploader middleware like this,

```
app.post('/uploadImage', uploader, function(req, res) {
   //file uploaded and callback received.
})
```

Comment: I am uploading pdf and png at a go

Comment: What's the issue with the upload?